# Getting client os ,os version, computer_name, mac id and device id

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, cordova, dom

I tried various types of the javascript library but, I am not able to get client os, os version, computer_name,  mac id and device id any once can help on this.

Answer (score 0):

By "client" I guess you mean "browser". Browsers have a Byzantine string built into them known as a user-agent string, at `navigator.userAgent` in the browser itself and in a `User-Agent` HTTP header visible from a server.

On my  Windows 10 / Google Chrome device it's

> Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.138 Safari/537.36

See? Only the scribes and prefects of medieval Byzantium could have dreamed that up.

Fortunately there's a nice npm package called [ua-parser-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ua-parser-js) that can yield machine type, os type and version, and browser type and version from that.

It shows a good example of use [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ua-parser-js#example).

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="ua-parser.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    var parser = new UAParser();

    // by default it takes ua string from fhe 
    // current browser's window.navigator.userAgent
    console.log(parser.getResult());

</script>
...
```

Be sure to keep your ua-parser code updated. Its authors crank out new versions regularly when new makes and models of device, operating system, or browser come out.